# MySQL ODBC Connection with SSL on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, odbc, iodbc

I'm trying to make and ODBC connection on my server that requires ssl. Here is my odbc.ini

```
RemoteConn= MySQL Unicode

[RemoteConn]
Driver      = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
Description = RemoteConn Connection
SERVER      = the remote IP Address
Database    = Remote DB Name
USER        = Remote DB USer
Password    = Remote DB Pass
sslkey      = /home/gzappy/RemoteConnCerts/client-key.pem
sslcert     = /home/gzappy/RemoteConnCerts/client-cert.pem
sslca       = /home/gzappy/RemoteConnCerts/ca-cert.pem
sslcapath   = /home/gzappy/RemoteConnCerts/
sslVerify   = 1
SSLMODE     = REQUIRED
```

and here is my odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Drivers]
MySQL Unicode = Installed
MYSQL ANSI    = Installed

[MySQL Unicode]
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
Setup  = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so

[MYSQL ANSI]
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8a.so
Setup  = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8a.so
```

When I run iodbctest, I can see my dsn, and when I select it I get the following output:

```
1: SQLDriverConnect =  (0) SQLSTATE=
1: ODBC_Connect = ⚌ (0) SQLSTATE=
```

What could be the problem, and how can I successfully connect to the ODBC?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing `sslkey to ssl-key sslcert to ssl-cert sslca to ssl-ca`